# How to return or get output value from stored procedure which is executing inside another proceed

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

i have  the following stored procedure :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spRptFundsTransferSchoolProfileSelect]          
(          
    @SessionID int ,      
    @DateRangeStart DateTime,       
    @DateRangeEnd DateTime       
)          
AS          
BEGIN        
 SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED     


    --set @SessionID = 1175      

    SELECT  tss.school_id,           
            ts.school_code,          
            tss.id,           
            ts.school_name,           
            ta.address,           
            ta.city,           
            ta.zip,            

    FROM T_School ts           

    Execute [dbo].[spRptFundsTransferPaymentSummarySelect]     @SessionID ,      
                                                               @DateRangeStart ,       
                                                               @DateRangeEnd       
END
```

and  following model for returning output :

```
namespace FundTr.de
{
    public class FundTrans : ModelBase
    {
        public string school_name { get; set; }

        public string school_code { get; set; }

        public int school_id { get; set; }

        public long id { get; set; }

        public string address { get; set; }

        public string city { get; set; }

        public string zip { get; set; }

        public string Date_Added { get; set; }//from dbo.spRptFundsTransferPaymentSummarySelect procedure

    }
}
```

contolller:

```
public ActionResult GetFundTransferReportTemplate(DateTime DateRangeStart, DateTime DateRangeEnd)
        {
            return SmartJson(ReportService.GetFundTransferReportTemplate(DateRangeStart, DateRangeEnd));

        }
```

service :

```
 public static FundTransferReportTemplate GetFundTransferReportTemplate(DateTime DateRangeStart, DateTime DateRangeEnd)
        {
            long SessionID = 1175;// SmartState.session.schoolSession.SessionId;
            var repo = GetRepository<FundTransferReportTemplate>();
            var da = repo.GetSingleObject("spRptFundsTransferSchoolProfileSelect", new { DateRangeStart, DateRangeEnd, SessionID });
            return da;

        }
```

when i hit the controller i get all value except last one "Date_Added"(this field from  procedure dbo.spRptFundsTransferPaymentSummarySelect).
i mean to say that i am not getting output value for dbo.spRptFundsTransferPaymentSummarySelect.how can i get
access output value of the procedure which is executing inside main procedure?

Answer (score 0):

The SP executes the top to bottom, in the sense, it will execute the `SELECT` statement and then execute the SP **spRptFundsTransferPaymentSummarySelect**. Assuming that the SP **spRptFundsTransferPaymentSummarySelect** returns a single value which is the **date_added**

You will need to call the **spRptFundsTransferPaymentSummarySelect** first and store the value in a variable `@Date_Added` and then use it in the `SELECT` statement.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spRptFundsTransferSchoolProfileSelect]
(
    @SessionID int,
    @DateRangeStart DateTime,
    @DateRangeEnd DateTime
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
    DECLARE @Date_Added DateTime

    Execute @Date_Added = [dbo].[spRptFundsTransferPaymentSummarySelect] @SessionID,
                                                                @DateRangeStart,
                                                                @DateRangeEnd

    --set @SessionID = 1175

    SELECT tss.school_id,
        ts.school_code,
        ts.id,
        ts.school_name,
        ta.address,
        ta.city,
        ta.zip,
        @Date_Added AS Date_Added
    FROM T_School ts
END
```

Comment: In case 1st SP returns more than one record the you will need to use CURSORS for the final output.